# Loop through the RectangleShape control

Tags: c#, vb.net

i want to loop through the form control RectangleShape  but they show me a ereur when i write the type of the controle ((RectangleShape))

```
  For Each cnt As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cnt Is RectangleShape Then

    End If
  Next
```

they show me this ereeur : "type 'RectangleShape' is not defined."

it works as well whene i use the control type TextBox or any other controls in the VS FORM like this :

```
For Each cnt As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cnt Is TextBox Then

    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?

Comment: this is it : type 'RectangleShape' is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spell out the full type name:

```
 If TypeOf cnt Is Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape Then
```

Or put this at the top of your source code file

```
 Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
```

But that won't work since RectangleShape is not a control.  It is hosted by a class named ShapeContainer.  You'll need code like this:

```
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is ShapeContainer Then
            For Each shape In DirectCast(ctl, ShapeContainer).Shapes
                If TypeOf shape Is RectangleShape Then
                    Dim rect = DirectCast(shape, RectangleShape)
                    '' do something
                    ''...
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

You might want to take advantage of the designer's ability to create a named variable for the rectangle.

Comment: and now they show me this msg :s :s : (( Expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' can never be of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape' )) 
tnks dudde ^^

Comment: i try this  For Each cnt As RectangleShape In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf cnt Is RectangleShape Then

                MsgBox(cnt.BackColor)
            End If
        Next

the list ereur is gone but the i execute the form  they show me this msg : ((Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer' to type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape'.))

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's a correct warning, it is not a control.  Post updated.  What the heck is a dudde?  My name is Hans.

Comment: what this variable can do to me ??? 
Dim rect = DirectCast(shape, RectangleShape)

Answer (score 2):

Sure just make cnt an Object so compiler can cast:

```
For Each cnt As Object In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cnt Is RectangleShape Then

    End If
Next
```

It's because no inheritance chain between `System.Windows.Control` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape`

Answer (score 0):

The shapes indeed are member of a ShapeContainer object. That can be detected by looking at the objects on a form, but there is a problem: Shapes can be put in any container object like panels and groupboxes, thus you need a lot of nesting down to the deepest level if you have shapes in a panel that itself is in a panel, etc... Shapecontainers are made an object within such containers at the moment that the first shape is put within that panel or groupbox. The numbering thus is unrelated to the numbering of the panel or groupbox.
I suppose that there are better ways to get the nesting (in other languages?), I tried with arrays, but that didn't work.

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is ShapeContainer Then
        For Each shape In DirectCast(ctl, ShapeContainer).Shapes
            'do something 
        Next
    Elseif TypeOf ctl Is Panel or Typeof ctl is GroepBox Then
        For Each ctl2 In DirectCast(ctl, Control).Controls
            If TypeOf ctl2 Is ShapeContainer Then
                For Each shape In DirectCast(ctl2, ShapeContainer).Shapes
                   'do something 
                Next
            Elseif  TypeOf ctl2 Is Panel or Typeof ctl2 is GroepBox Then
                For Each ctl3 In DirectCast(ctl2, Control).Controls
                    If TypeOf ctl3 Is ShapeContainer Then
                        For Each shape In DirectCast(ctl3, ShapeContainer).Shapes
                            'do something 
                        Next
                    Elseif TypeOf ctl3 Is Panel or Typeof ctl3 is GroepBox Then
                        'goto next level...
                    End if
                Next
            End If
        Next       
    End If
Next
```